# How can I optimize this bash script to set my backlight brighness in incraments of 5% without rounding errors?

Tags: bash

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

blDir='/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight'
brightness=$(cat $blDir/brightness) # current brightness
max=$(cat $blDir/max_brightness)    # maximum brightness
percentage=$(echo "scale=3; ($brightness/$max)*100" | bc | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}')

case $BLOCK_BUTTON in
    # brightness up %5
    4) echo $(( $brightness + ( $max / 20 ) )) > $blDir/brightness ;;   
    # brightness down %5
    5) echo $(( $brightness - ( $max / 20 ) )) > $blDir/brightness ;;   
esac

if (( $percentage >= 5 )); then
    # output current brightness
    echo "☀ $percentage%"
else
    # output '0%' instead of '%'
    echo "☀ 0%"
fi
```

This is a script to display and let me adjust the backlight brightness in my window manager's status bar. Whatever I echo from this script is what appears in the status bar. The asterisk-looking thing in the output is just a unicode sun icon. $BLOCK_BUTTON is the button that I press while the cursor is hovered over it, with 4 representing scroll-up and 5 representing scroll-down. It displays the current brighness just fine. Whenever I scroll up, it brings the brightness up from 0% to 55% in incraments of 5%. Then it goes to 59%, 64%, 69%, 74%, etc. Why is it doing this? Is this some sort of rounding error? How can I fix it so that it goes in incraments of 5% up to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest counting the difference between the value of current brightness and the value to set at each step depending on the leftover to max. This way, the rounding errors won't cumulate.

With the literal max value of my machine, here's the demo:

```
$> cat tuner.sh

current=0
max=4437
for step in {0..19}; do
   diff=$(echo "($max - $current)  / (20-$step)" | bc )
   current=$(echo "$current + $diff" | bc )
   echo "$current / $max"
done

$> ./tuner.sh
221 / 4437
442 / 4437
663 / 4437
885 / 4437
1107 / 4437
1329 / 4437
1551 / 4437
1773 / 4437
1995 / 4437
2217 / 4437
2439 / 4437
2661 / 4437
2883 / 4437
3105 / 4437
3327 / 4437
3549 / 4437
3771 / 4437
3993 / 4437
4215 / 4437
4437 / 4437
```

If the difference is always the same, then the errors add up:

```
$> cat badtuner.sh

current=0
max=4437
for step in {0..19}; do
   diff=$(echo "$max / 20" | bc )
   current=$(echo "$current + $diff" | bc )
   echo "$current / $max"
done

$> ./badtuner.sh
221 / 4437
442 / 4437
663 / 4437
884 / 4437
1105 / 4437
1326 / 4437
1547 / 4437
1768 / 4437
1989 / 4437
2210 / 4437
2431 / 4437
2652 / 4437
2873 / 4437
3094 / 4437
3315 / 4437
3536 / 4437
3757 / 4437
3978 / 4437
4199 / 4437
4420 / 4437
```

For this recommendation, you must have a step counter stored in order to know what your current divisor should be to compute the difference.